# How to fix border overlapping when windows has 150% scalling

Tags: html, css

When the windows is on 100% scalling, the border width/thickness has the same size, while on 150% scalling, the border has different width/thickness depending on the browser zoom.

Here the HTML code.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Irvan</td>
            <td>21 Years Old</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Riza</td>
            <td>21 Years Old</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And for example i'm using this css code.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

[Here the result that i'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4szs1.png)

After reviewing few question and answer, i don't find any matching solution for this issues, like using.

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px;
```

I also tried using `border: 0.1px solid #ddd` but the border ended looks too thin, but at the same width/tickness in any % of zoom.

As the detail information from this link, it's a browser scalling issues.

> silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-fix-windows-scaling-issues-above-100-for-your-website

I also tried the solution, but the overlap keep appearing, i worried it's render issues with my hardware or something that not the coding problem.

NOTE

Windows 10 Professional (21H1 Build 19043.1165)
Scale : 150% (Recommended)
Resolution : 1920 x 1080 (Recommended)

Thanks